# Jasper Report Excel column segmentation

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

Requirement: Develop 10 reports and navigate to each report when clicking on the hyper link placed on the navigation menu.

While exporting to excel each sub reports should come in separate excel sheets and the excel column segmentation should match the report columns. 
90% work done.

**Only excel segmentation issue remains.**

[image: Excel ouput]

I Developed a main Jasper Report .

1. Placed all the sub reports in separate groups.
2. added a text field with property     net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row after each sub report element.(for splitting report in separate sheets)
3. reports are coming in separate excel sheets but their column segmentation problem still there .

Below is the JRXML I'm using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TOSMetricsReport" pageWidth="3000" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="2780" leftMargin="200" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="82356077-f8a3-4fb5-92de-af77228a6b21">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.one.page.per.sheet " value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.create.batch.mode.bookmarks" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="background"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.group.1" value="break"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.exclude.origin.band.1" value="background"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.wrap.text" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.row" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.auto.fit.column" value="true"/>
    <parameter name="year" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 1]]>
    </queryString>
    <group name="Group1"/>
    <group name="Group2">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="44">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.column.width.ratio" value="1000"/>
                <subreport runToBottom="true">
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="2" y="6" width="60" height="38" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="dca34dc6-3ae1-4154-9f39-aefda281942b"/>
                    <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Roadmap.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="break">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="11">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="100" height="1" uuid="ddf8561d-a742-4ee5-9504-4e2b4a979735">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band height="332" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" hyperlinkTarget="Top" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="-170" y="0" width="170" height="30" uuid="e8a3ca2e-8d8d-4913-8da7-dfdd33561fc8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Roadmap"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["Roadmap"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
                <hyperlinkTooltipExpression><![CDATA["Roadmap"]]></hyperlinkTooltipExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" hyperlinkTarget="Top" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="-170" y="240" width="170" height="30" uuid="2cbd23e8-4e2c-4107-a0f7-3997ae2f4a2f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cost Center FINApprovers"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["CostCenter"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="30" width="170" height="30" uuid="460205c5-cffd-42bb-bf05-9292f2120c31"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Performance"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["per"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="60" width="170" height="30" uuid="e7425be8-cf87-48e7-8a93-7b1b91f55c40"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["CC Owners & Leads"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["cco"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="90" width="170" height="30" uuid="7173485a-c0ba-4d49-8a19-3ac6b55cff7f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Incomplete key Milestones"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["ikm"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="120" width="170" height="30" uuid="ddf9fea7-bf9a-4f18-a29b-5dee53d2e26c"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Deployment Forecast"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["df"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="150" width="170" height="30" uuid="c8fbbc99-d593-4296-b02d-abefd3d795c1"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Unfunded"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["uf"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="180" width="170" height="30" uuid="c8fbbc99-d593-4296-b02d-abefd3d795c1"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Financials - LT & FY"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["fin"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="-170" y="210" width="169" height="30" uuid="2c7eb592-f4b4-4f05-95e9-cbfe6882821f"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Divisional Plan Milestone"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["dpm"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="-170" y="270" width="169" height="30" uuid="f498ca0f-2fdb-4e07-af15-2ed48fb26502"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["RiskScore"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <hyperlinkAnchorExpression><![CDATA["rs"]]></hyperlinkAnchorExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="791" height="30" uuid="622c8818-d378-4b4b-ae4b-7e37ff18c760"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="20" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PMO  METRICS EXTRACT]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="33">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="0" width="59" height="30" uuid="95611b1b-88c8-47d6-a77d-13a9f69316d3"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Performance.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="32" width="100" height="1" uuid="c841c3ff-c3df-4464-8a4c-9ef7d09dffcd">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="44">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="5" width="59" height="38" uuid="f8b8bc34-7a99-46c5-bab9-09381626c1bd"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/CC_Owners_&_Leads.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="43" width="100" height="1" uuid="6e9de47b-7f05-4785-8d1f-3457d3d96c1a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="51">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="0" width="59" height="48" uuid="02a75b6e-cb02-46d7-873f-4a24b462f2a1"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Incomplete_Key_Milestones.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="50" width="100" height="1" uuid="12901493-5c87-40d2-a093-193b20127d0d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="35">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="4" width="59" height="28" uuid="ac55415d-032e-40a0-8e1f-5ea5ae1f2d8d"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Deployment_Forecast.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="34" width="100" height="1" uuid="a9701cb8-1898-426f-abf3-f503bd2c6be7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="30">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="0" width="60" height="27" uuid="6d044dc9-ccc1-45dc-8d8d-e85e3ac6146b"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Unfunded.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="29" width="100" height="1" uuid="f0a180e0-0c66-4865-8fe4-13a1e78ba69f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="30">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="4" width="59" height="25" uuid="c59580ac-a620-48e7-aa27-3c605b7284a3"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Financials - LT & FY.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="29" width="100" height="1" uuid="0894fa3a-1f37-4747-a501-aef8fe997482">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="31">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="0" width="60" height="28" uuid="b4aa0a9a-1024-4fbe-8ed7-0e7feb418c01"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Divisional_Plan_Milestone.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="1" uuid="6699d708-6447-4458-bd25-fe064bf990b2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="32">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="1" width="60" height="28" uuid="9fd474cf-ac38-4de2-a644-ccc9c88fc287"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/CostCenterFINApprovers.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="31" width="100" height="1" uuid="a077ff9d-f999-4f95-89ad-d7e909360465">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
        <band height="32">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="3" y="0" width="60" height="30" uuid="e8ae422b-705a-4c48-badd-d955fa7f6d47"/>
                <parametersMapExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}]]></parametersMapExpression>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["ReportDevelopment/PMO/Riskss.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="31" width="100" height="1" uuid="7dbf13dc-74fc-4726-8a13-21d6835312f0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["break Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Please have a look at it

Answer (score -1):

To make Excel have fewer columns, you must be very careful in designing the report for fields in the same page that have similar X location and W size (but differ in their Y location).  They must have the same X coordinate and W length, or you will get multiple columns, as in your example.

Doesn't work:  Field 1 X=100 px, Y=100 px, W=50 px.  Field2 X=101 px, Y=150 px, W=51 px.  This would produce 3 columns.  100 to 101, 101 to 150, 150 to 151.

Do this instead: Field 1 X=100 px, Y=100 px, W=50 px.  Field2 X=100 px, Y=150 px, W=50 px.  This would produce 1 column.  100 to 150.